# Camel: defer ActiveMQ messages until error condition gets resolved

Tags: error-handling, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I've got a service implemented in a Camel route that consumes messages from an ActiveMQ queue, does some processing and sends them to an external system.

If something goes wrong while calling the external system, the message ID has to be notified back to the calling backend system. Since the message order must be maintained, the service needs to defer the the already enqueued and the following messages until the error condition is resolved.

In fact the failed message has to be removed from the queue, since it has been processed, ableit failed. This may be a difference compared to a Camel redelivery.

The backend system shall be in control of the further process. Either it sends the message in question again, then the service should process this one message (identified by its ID) and then continue to process the deferred ones. Or the backend sends some continuation signal that signals the service to continue processing the deferred messages although the failed one did not appear again. Both options resolve the error condition.

So far I've thought of implementing some sort of Camel based switching involving multiple queues, where the route decides if it can process the incoming message directly or if there are deferred ones to process. But I don't have an idea if there are some EIPs to depict this scenario in a neat way.

Can you give some advise to me on an camelish approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like (at least to me) an orchestrated workflow vs a single EIP-- b/c you are describing the need to maintain state across multiple steps. This can totally can be done with event driven systems, but generally becomes brittle when trying to force it into a use only one queue solution and single EIP.

The multiple-queue / multiple Camel route approach would be straight-forward and not require any unnatural acts (stopping routes, re-queuing everything, etc) to generally maintain message ordering, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the Resequencer EIP to put some priority on failed retried exchange : http://camel.apache.org/resequencer.html.

Comment: As far as I understand Resequencer, it's not an option for my specific problem. When going into fail state the input queue can grow by an unknown number of incoming messages. Resequencer waits for a size-limited batch or timeouts. Maybe the backend sends a continuation signal a couple of days later. Delivery of out-of-sequence messages is not allowed.